# How to run a Google Glass GDK sample on the device?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-glass, google-gdk

I start developing Google Glass app with GDK .

I use Eclipse with Android SDK Manager to install the GDK.

After that, I import the Google Glass project following the steps mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start):

1. Click **File > New Project > Android Sample Project**
2. Select **Glass Development Kit** as the build target and click Next.
3. Select the **Timer** sample and click **Finish**.
4. In the Eclipse Package Explorer, right click the sample and select **Run as > Android Application** with Glass connected to your development system.

The Google Glass (version XE12) is connected, but nothing shows up. Then, I follow another [tutorial](http://blog.glassdiary.com/post/67451300016/my-first-gdk-app-on-google-glass) online to launch the App manually using an `adb` command:

```
./adb shell am start -n com.google.android.glass.sample.timer/.MenuActivity
```

But the result is a Permission Denial:

```
$ ./adb shell am start -n com.google.android.glass.sample.timer/.MenuActivity
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.glass.sample.timer/.MenuActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.glass.sample.timer/.MenuActivity } from null (pid=2938, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10032
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1631)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:441)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:108)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:81)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.finishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:238)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How to solve the problem ?

On the other hand, I made an App similar to the Android example using Eclipse. After I click Run as > Android Application in Eclipse menu bar, the console said:

```
[2014-01-06 18:55:10 - Glass001] Android Launch!
[2014-01-06 18:55:10 - Glass001] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-06 18:55:10 - Glass001] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-01-06 18:55:10 - Glass001] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2014-01-06 18:55:10 - Glass001] Performing sync
[2014-01-06 18:55:10 - Glass001] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-01-06 18:55:17 - Glass001] Uploading Glass001.apk onto device '015DBXXXXXX701C'
[2014-01-06 18:55:17 - Glass001] Installing Glass001.apk...
[2014-01-06 18:55:20 - Glass001] Success!
[2014-01-06 18:55:20 - Glass001] /Glass001/bin/Glass001.apk installed on device
[2014-01-06 18:55:20 - Glass001] Done!
[2014-01-06 18:56:48 - Glass001] ------------------------------
```

Does this relate to the error message "No Launcher activity found!" ? Referring to this error, I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12384191/188331) in Stack Overflow. Where should I put the lines in the following `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.glass.sample.timer"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_timer"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.sample.timer.MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MenuTheme"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.sample.timer.SetTimerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.sample.timer.SelectValueActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.sample.timer.TimerService"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_timer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger_start" />
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Debug mode of Google Glass is ON (Yes, I can see the device in Eclipse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set up a debug configuration that will work for this. Originally this application won't start without user interaction. If you go to the debug drop-down and say configure you can have it auto start an activity of your choice. So at the top pick the project then when it asks what to do say auto launch activity with the drop-down box next to it. Use the drop-down to select the activity you want to auto-start. Then try debugging the application and it should push and start automatically on your glass.

Comment: *debug drop-down and say configure you can have it auto start an activity of your choice* where is it ? in the Glass menu / in Eclipse? I am new to Google Glass.

Comment: This option is in eclipse. It should be at the top next to the bug button you will have a drop-down and one of the options will be debug configuration or edit configuration.

Comment: Also if you want to hard code the activity to start I would just add the intent lines into the service because that is what usually launches when you do the voice command from the "ok glass" command screen. that is why you see the intent-filter in the service.

Comment: It works! Strangely by default, there's no Default Activity to launch.

Comment: That is because for Google Glass you have activities fired from voice intents not by defaults.