# Loading Google Glass GDK sample

Tags: android, eclipse, google-glass, google-gdk

I have a problem to load [Google Glass GDK sample](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start) (Compass, Stopwatch, or Timer) to my google-glass. I use Eclipse for this. In the console, it shows me successful message

> [2014-04-20 19:42:56 - Compass] Installing Compass.apk... [2014-04-20
>   19:42:58 - Compass] Success! [2014-04-20 19:42:58 - Compass]
>   /Compass/bin/Compass.apk installed on device [2014-04-20 19:42:58 -
>   Compass] Done!

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949392/how-to-run-a-google-glass-gdk-sample-on-the-device?rq=1) suggests I use a voice trigger to activate the service (e.g.: "ok glass, show a compass"). But it doesn't work for me. 
I also tried another suggestion from [different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949392/how-to-run-a-google-glass-gdk-sample-on-the-device?rq=1) to go to Run/ Debug configuration to specify exactly which activity to run. But in my case, the "Launch" option under "Android" Tab doesn't give me any selection.

My google glass version is currently XE12.1

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Where are you grabbing the sample projects from?  If they are from the Android SDK API Level 19 samples folder, or Github (https://github.com/googleglass/), then these projects have been updated to work with XE16 and won't work on XE12.X.  You'll need to use the samples under the API Level 15 folder on XE12.X, and they are activated by voice command (e.g., "ok glass, show a compass").

Comment: Sean is correct. After I update to XE16, it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sample projects you are using are from the Android SDK API Level 19 samples folder, or [Github](https://github.com/googleglass), then these projects have been updated to work with XE16 and won't work on XE12.X.

You'll need to use the samples under the API Level 15 folder on XE12.X.

Or, update your Glass to XE16, and then the most recent version of the samples should work for you.

All versions of sample projects are activated by voice command (e.g., "ok glass, show a compass").

Answer (score 0):

Use this adb command from the command line on a PC or Terminal on a mac:

```
adb shell am start -n com.google.android.glass.sample.compass/com.google.android.glass.sample.compass.CompassMenuActivity
```

While Glass is ADB connected and is the only ADB device connected.

This should launch the Compass activity for you on XE12.

I got the package name and activity name from here:

https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-compass-sample/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml

Perhaps if you are using different code, you'll need to tweak the adb shell command.