# Can't run sample apps on Glass, device not visible in Android Device Chooser

Tags: android, eclipse, google-glass

*(Incase the screenshots look too small, please right-click and 'open image in a new tab')*

I was following the steps here - https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start

I turned on debugging on the Glass. Downloaded ADT. Connected the Glass via USB to my Mac - I saw it in the DDMS perspective as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: DDMS Perspective]

Now I opened a sample project called 'Timer' and tried to run it as an 'Android application', when it asked me to choose an 'Android device' or create a virtual one, as you can see in the android device chooser screenshot.

[image: Android Device Chooser]

I have also added a screenshot of the Android SDK manager which shows the installed packages.

[image: Android SDK Manager - Installed packages]

The confusing aspect for me is that the Google Glass shows up as a 4.04 device on the DDMS perspective. When I check out device info on the Glass itself, it shows XE12.1 as being installed. However, when I explored, it seems that XE16 is the latest upgrade which brings KitKat to Glass. I did read some stuff about Google halting Glass updates [here](http://blogs.cio.com/consumer-technology/18544/google-halts-glass-xe16-software-update), which might be why I can't upgrade beyond 12.1.

However, the Glass Development Kit Preview only shows up under Android 4.4.2 (API 19) in the SDK Manager when I list all available packages. Is that causing some incompatibility issues given that my Glass is a 4.04?

I'm using a Mac with OSX 10.9

*(Incase the screenshots look too small, please right-click and 'open image in a new tab')*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23222757/937715

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390624/ddms-unable-to-see-google-glass/20412429#20412429  it's for windows, but i suppose in OSX could be done. After doing that i could see Google Glass as device in eclipse.